# Jackson JsonParser get Array token

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, fasterxml

I am using Jackson Json Parser to get values out of a JSON string and then plugging them into a Java Object. Here is a chunk of the sort of JSON I am dealing with:

```
{
    "address":"aURL",
    "links":[
        "aURL",
        "aURL",
        "aURL"
    ]
}
```

Here is what I have going on in my Java code. net is a global ArrayList, Page objects have a String address field and a String[] links field. I want to get the String array of links out of the JSON and plug them into a Page object. While I can easily extract the address string with the getText() method, I cannot figure a convenient way to just grab the String array. Here's my code right now:

```
private static void parse(String json) throws IOException {
    JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createJsonParser(json);
    while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String tok = parser.getCurrentName();
        Page p = new Page();
        if ("address".equals(tok)) {
            parser.nextToken();
            p.setAddress(parser.getText());
        }
        if ("links".equals(tok)) {
            parser.nextToken();
            //p.setLinks(HOW TO GET STRING ARRAY)
        }
        net.add(p);
    }
}
```

I would prefer to stick with the JsonParser nexting method I am using, unless it's just gonna be too unwieldy.

Comment: Any particular reason for not using something much simpler like Gson ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
private static void parse(String json) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createJsonParser(json);
    while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String tok = parser.getCurrentName();
        Page p = new Page();
        if ("address".equals(tok)) {
            parser.nextToken();
            p.setAddress(parser.getText());
        }
        if ("links".equals(tok)) {
            parser.nextToken();
            ArrayNode node = objectMapper.readTree(parser);
            Iterator<JsonNode> iterator = node.elements();
            String[] array = new String[node.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < node.size(); i++) {
                if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    array[i] = iterator.next().asText();
                }
            }
            p.setLinks(array);
        }
        net.add(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: the String[] links is still coming up null

Comment: I just checked it again. It works fine for me. please verify again.

Comment: I switched around some things elsewhere in my program and this did end up working out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this;

```
if ("links".equals(tok)) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    parser.nextToken();
    if (parser.currentToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
        parser.nextToken();
        while (parser.currentToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            list.add(parser.getText());
            parser.nextToken();
        }
    }
    p.setLinks(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
}
```